# JQuery autofill performance Issues

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, database-performance

I am using Jquery autocomplete feature to load some ItemCodes from Items table in SQL Server DB.

Items table contains : Item Codes, Item Name, Item Description

I am able to get auto complete feature working, but the problem is Items table contains around 230,000 records and search is slower.

I have enabled autocomplete from 5th character rather than 2nd or 3rd character. However its still slow.. results get loaded in some 30 seconds which is long time to load autocomplete. I understand this is due to the number of records i'm dealing with.

One idea i could think of (may be entirely wrong) is to load dropdown only if the number of records matching the input string are less than some 20.

Any suggestions on how we can improve the performance please?

---

**Edit 1**

***HTML Page:***

```
function SearchText() {
    $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "../My_Service.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                data: "{'ItemSubStr':'" + document.getElementById( "<%=txtCISearchInput.ClientID%>").value + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data.d);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**In ASP.Net**

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function GetAutoCompleteData(ByVal ItemSubStr As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim result As New List(Of String)()
    If ItemSubStr.Length < 4 Then
        Return result
    End If
    Dim sConnection As String = "XXXXXXXXX"
    Using Con As New SqlConnection(sConnection)
        Con.Open()
        Using Com As New SqlCommand("select distinct ItemCodes from Items where ItemCodes  like '%" + ItemSubStr + "%' order by 1", Con)
            Using RDR = Com.ExecuteReader()
                If RDR.HasRows Then
                    Do While RDR.Read
                        result.Add(RDR.Item("ItemCodes").ToString())
                    Loop
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
        Con.Close()
    End Using
    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: Optimize code, add indexes to columns.

Comment: take a look at this http://www.pontikis.net/blog/jquery-ui-autocomplete-step-by-step

Comment: @Justinas : we already have Index on required column, Here i have edited my question with the code, Can you suggest areas where i can optimize the code. Thanks for your time

Comment: What indexes you have on what columns?

Comment: @Kermani : I have checked the article mate, it about creating the autocomplete. In my case i got it working, but its slow on performance as table got around 230,000 records.

Comment: @Justinas : I have clustered index on Item Code and Non Clustered Index on Item Name